# empty emails with mfmailcomposeviewcontroller ... foreign language issues?

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using mfmailcomposeviewcontroller in my app for users to email me about issues etc... pretty basic right. This controller has the 'cancel' & 'send' button in it so if users didn't want to send anything they could just cancel.

Recently I've been getting a lot of feedback/support emails from a lot of my app users with no content in it. Could this be due to some locale or language setting ? Is there some sort of encoding I need to enable while sending the email back to me ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

`application/pdf;charset=UTF-8` mimetype, not just `application/pdf`.

Comment: how did this fix the issue?